# How to query nested documents in mongoDB using $in

Tags: mongodb

So I have a collection with documents like this:

```
"id": "123",
"vendorId":"VVVVV",
"dc": {
  "id": "0123",
  "name": "XX"
},
"item": {
  "id": "0000456",
  "description": "YY"
}
```

and I want to query a range of dc.id and item.id, like this:

```
{ "dc.id" : { "$in" : ["0123", "0234"]}, "item.id" : { "$in" : ["0000456", "0000999"]}}
```

There are documents in the collection with both these values as dc.id and item.id, but this query always return only the documents that match the first of each $in clause, so in this example above, it only returns documents where dc.id="0123" and item.id="0000456".

Is there a way to query documents by their nested document fields using $in?
If so, what am I doing wrong?

---

UPDATE:
Example of documents in the collection:

```json
[ {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "64ac06fed2accfe45bbcd66c"
    },
    "vendorId": "V",
    "distributionCenter": {
      "id": "0045",
      "name": "CI"
    },
    "item": {
      "sku": "0000253",
      "description": "SU"
    }
  },{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "64adc04ac7e1f8a32a7be654"
    },
    "vendorId": "V",
    "distributionCenter": {
      "_id": "0966",
      "name": "CS"
    },
    "item": {
      "sku": "0000999",
      "description": "LN"
    }
  }
]
```

Query I'm using and it's returning only one of these documents:

```
{"distributionCenter._id": {"$in":["0966","0045"]}, "item.sku":{"$in":["0000999","0000253"]}}
```

Comment: Nothing looks obviously wrong about this too me at a glance. Can you provide a sample document that is failing to match or, better yet, share a mongoplayground link demonstrating the problem?

Comment: All passing combinations of `dc.id` and `item.id` work fine on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2XTZys4Gr9j).

Comment: Consider to store numeric values as number instead of strings.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit as you can see in the examples given, the numbers must have zeroes at the beginning.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I'm using MongoDB 4.4 and mongoplayground works on 6.0, maybe this was fixed on some recent version?

Comment: Would you show a document that should match your query, but for an as yet unknown reason, does not?

Comment: In your update documents, the first document has `"distributionCenter.id"` instead of `"distributionCenter._id"`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I saw this before and I thought I had changed it here in my test, but now I checked and I haven't. I did now, and it worked, thanks very much for your time.